# c# Find value in a range using lambda

Tags: c#, list, find, range

I'm trying to find an item in a list of values based on another value using a lambda expression using the Find method. In this example I'm expecting to get back -1000, but for the life of me, I just can't come up with the proper lamda expression. If that sounds confusing I hope the code and comments below explain it better.
TIA.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestingStuff {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            double amount = -200;

            //The Range of values
            List<MyValue> values = new List<MyValue>();
            values.Add(new MyValue(-1000));
            values.Add(new MyValue(-100));
            values.Add(new MyValue(-10));
            values.Add(new MyValue(0));
            values.Add(new MyValue(100));
            values.Add(new MyValue(1000));

            //Find it!!!  
            MyValue fVal = values.Find(x => (x.Value > amount) && (x.Value < amount));

            //Expecting -1000 as a result here since -200 falls between -1000 and -100
            //if it were -90 I'd expect -100 since it falls between -100 and 0
            if (fVal != null)
                Console.WriteLine(fVal.Value);            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MyValue {
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public MyValue(double value) {
            Value = value;
        }        
    }
}
```

Mmm let me put my intentions a little clearer by specifying all the expected results.

-1000 and less to -101 should give -1000  
-100 to - 11 should give -100  
-10 to -1 should give -10  
0 to 9 should give 0  
10 to 99 should give 10  
100-999 should give 100  
1000 or more should give 1000

Comment: If you use +200, what are you expecting?

Comment: If you use -100, do you expect -1000 or -100 as a result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
values.FindLast(x => amount >= x.Value);
```

Comment: Awesome this is percect. How elegant!

Comment: Hold on, maybe not 100% this caters for all the instance even 10000000 which should give 1000 but it does not cater for -100000 which should give -1000. I could just add a very very large negative value to the start of my list though and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You did a logical mistake ... a value can't be > -200 AND < -200 at the same time .. U need the OR expression ( "||" )

```
 MyValue fVal = values.Find(x => (x.Value > amount) || (x.Value < amount));
```

But if you expect to get -1000 this expression is also wrong

```
 MyValue fVal = values.Find(x => (x.Value < amount));
```

Because -1000 is SMALLER than -200

EDIT : Ok I think I missunderstood your intention. But the way you want to select your value doesn't seem logical to me. Do you want the next smaller value ?

Comment: I have updated the main question, with all the expected results. Please see there. What I basically want is to do a between like you would in a SQL statement when searching for results that fall between two dates except these are numbers.

EG:

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE
CreationDate > '2010-03-01'
AND CreationDate < '2010-03-31'

Which finds all users between 1 Mar and 31 Mar.
Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

I'm making the assumption that if you used the value +90, you'd expect 100 and not zero, as well as if you use 200, you're expecting 1000 and not 100.

```
MyValue fVal = values
    .Where(x => amount > 0 ? x.Value > amount : x.Value < amount)
    .OrderBy(x => amount > 0 ? x.Value : -x.Value).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the same assumption as Darksider Another option would be

```
MyValue fVal = values.Find(x => Math.Abs(x.Value) > amount && (x.Value<0 == amount<0));
```

of course this relies on the list already being sorted.  Darksider's solution may be better if  the list might not be sorted alreday.

Comment: Julien's works correctly in my case except for very small negative values. I'll just add a very small negative value in the list and all should be fine.